# NullPointerException with Unsafe Class in Java

Tags: java, exception

When using `Unsafe.getByte(byte[], long)` or `Unsafe.putByte(long, byte[])` or any other get/put method for other primitive types in Unsafe, I will get a NullPointerException.
Here is the code segment:

```
byte[] data = new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
long offset = 0;
Unsafe unsafe = getUnsafe();

public byte at(long index) {
    return unsafe.getByte(data, index + this.offset);
}
```

*All field are instantiated correctly.
*Method getUnsafe() will return a Unsafe class instance.

Comment: Please post some relevant code that will help the community to better diagnose what the problem might be.

Comment: Please post code you have actually compiled or run. `byte[] data = new data[] {...};` cannot compile, because `data` is not the same type as `byte`.

Comment: edited, typo :P The actually code are confidential, sorry about that

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that your assertion / assumption that the fields are correctly initialized is in fact false.  But on the other hand, you are using a class that (IMO) you should avoid using at all costs ... because it is **unsafe**.  Bad things can happen.

Comment: Also, read the caveats here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/misc/Unsafe.java#Unsafe.getInt%28java.lang.Object%2Clong%29  (And yes, I know I referred to the getInt method ...)

Comment: Just to be sure, pls add `if (unsafe==null || data==null) throw new NullPointerException("unsafe or data");` just before the call. As your real code differs, also check that you're not using boxed primitives there (which may be `null` and sometimes it takes time to find out what's wrong).

Answer (score 1):

If I try your code, I get a `java.lang.SecurityException` for `Unsafe.getUnsafe()`. If you somehow ignore that exception, `unsafe` might end up being `null`, which could be the cause of your exception.

If I instead use the following code to initialize `unsafe`:

```
Unsafe unsafe = null;

try {
    Field field = sun.misc.Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    unsafe = (sun.misc.Unsafe) field.get(null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new AssertionError(e);
}
```

everything works and I can use your `at(...)` function to access the bytes in the array, if I set `offset` to 16. Maybe try this and see if it helps.

**BUT!!!** (as @StephenC said above), you should try to avoid using this method! For example, you might not be able to rely on a specific value of `offset` applying to all VMs. Also, in some crazy cases, some VMs might even decide to word-align the bytes in your array so that you need to increment `index` by 4 or 8 to get to the next byte (this is a guess). This function might be highly unpredictable. I also doubt that it is much faster than just using `data[index]`, since you just introduced a method-call into your code. If you need speed, also make sure to look into [direct NIO ByteBuffers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect%28int%29).

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, just one correction to your answer. `getUnsafe()` is a custom method which will return a Unsafe instance without throwing `java.lang.SecurityException` BUT your answer is still very helpful :)

Comment: It's a bit difficult to really understand what's going on. A bit more of your code and some info about the error might be helpful...